# Using Doctrine with views - dud 'id' field generated

Tags: php, mysql, view, doctrine, yaml

I have a DB (yes, that one) which is proving far easier to access via views than raw tables. In general this plays quite nicely with Doctrine, but there's one issue. Doctrine can't identify a primary key in a view table when generating the YAML from the database schema, so it invents one called 'id'. Generating classes from this means that all queries fail on the lack of this id field.

Is there any way you can hint to the generator script that it shouldn't create this field, and point it to one that's more appropriate? I can see how to do it in the YAML, or in a class with annotations, but no way to do it in the DB.

Suggestions welcome.

*(Anyone following my questions (why?) will probably have worked out how much fun I'm having with both Doctrine and this database. I think it's called a "learning experience".)*

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to do it in the YAML but you can just remove the the definition of the ID column from the generated PHP (Base) file. Not the most "elegant" solution but I think Doctrine's convetnion is to always add a Primary Key.

BTW, is there anything usefull for you at http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/component-overview/en#views?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps not exactly what you asked but
another solution is to put this in the model class

```
public function setUp() {
    Doctrine_Core::getTable('your_view_name')->removeColumn('id');
    parent::setUp();
}
```

hope it helps someone with this problem